# When installed datadog APM ddtrace php then my app not working

Tags: php, datadog, apm

I was installed the "datadog-php-tracer_0.14.1-beta_amd64.deb" on my server and after installed my application return 500 error.

Below is the things which I have configured or my server related information:

I am using Ubuntu, NGINX and php-fpm 7.0.

I have installed datadog agent v6.

```
For FPM I have set below configuration:
Installed : "datadog-php-tracer_0.14.1-beta_amd64.deb"
NGINX config: fastcgi_param DD_TRACE_DEBUG true;
Set ddtrace.log_backtrace=1 in file /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/98-ddtrace.ini.

In Agent datadog.yaml:
apm_config:
  enabled: true
```

When I am checking my php-fpm log file, it shows the PDO error about "Slim\PDO\Statement\StatementContainer->execute()". But when I disabled the Datadog Agent or APM trace then my application working normally. In short when I am enable ddtrace my app not working and return 500 error.

Can you please look in it and let me know how can resolved the issue and APM work well with my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I posted the issue on GitHub, they give an answer the issue was in source code for dd-trace-php and they will fix and new release.
https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php/issues/334

Below response of DatDog in github:

Ah now this is much more clear, thanks for sharing. This is a known problem that we are currently and actively working on. As I cannot commit to that, the fix will be probably come out with the next release.

At an higher level, the cause is an issue we have in some specific cases while invoking private/protected methods and parent::* invocations.

In the meantime, if you are still interested in testing/using the other integrations, the only thing I can recommend is to disable the pdo integration: **fastcgi_param DD_INTEGRATIONS_DISABLED pdo**.

Again, the fix to this is currently in development and will be released very soon.